# Keep text in bottom of page in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, touch

Following this question: [How to put text in the upper right, or lower right corner of a "box" using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536/how-to-put-text-in-the-upper-right-or-lower-right-corner-of-a-box-using-css), I created this code:

```
#copyright {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 2;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#creator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

In a computer it works fine. However when I test it through Google's Chrome emulator for mobiles, the text won't go to the bottom after a scroll, like a sticky footer would do. I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2w4jjyt/21/), but it seems to fail to reproduce the behavior, so I took a screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `position: fixed`, not `absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `position: relative` to the `body` element.

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

In doing so, the `#copyright`/`#creator` elements will be positioned absolutely *relative* to the `body` element, which is what you want in this case.

Comment: Well, yours is ideal for mobile devices in my case, while the other case is perfect for the desktop, so I think I am going to use media-queries here. You see, I had tried yours, but I didn't like it, because it made my page scroll (in the desktop).

Comment: Yeah, it's perfect for a mobile device, thanks! :) However, I am going to accept the low-rep user's answer, to give him/her a boost!!! :D

Comment: @gsamaras Haha, yeah, definitely :) Plus they answered first anyways.

Comment: Josh I am terribly sorry, but I remembered our previous discussion. That's why, sorry again.